# Call to a member function isEmpty() on a non-object?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I make my view in the controller via:

```
$data = Lib::index();
    $view = View::make('index')
        ->with('data', $data)
        ->render();
    return $view;
```

I can check if data is empty in the controller via:

```
$data->isEmpty();
```

But when I try the same thing in the view I get the error:

```
Call to a member function isEmpty() on a non-object
```

Why?

Here's the code for Lib::index():

```
   $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? ($_GET['page']) : 1;

    Paginator::setCurrentPage($page);

    try {
        $data = Asset::with(array('sizes'=> function($query){
            $query->select('width', 'height', 'asset_id');
        }))->where('active', 1)->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->paginate(Config::get('p.results_per_page'), array('id', 'alt'));
    }

    catch (QueryException $e) {

        App::abort(404);
    }


    return $data;
```

Comment: Show the code for `Lib::index()`

Answer (score 5):

`isEmpty()` is a Collection method. For some weird reasons, in views, it sometimes refer to an empty Collection as `null`. The safest check, in my opinion would be to do a counts check, like so:

```
if (count($data)) {...}
```

This works well both in Controllers and Views.

Answer (score 3):

consider you are getting some information as collection;

```
$UserInfo = User::where('phone', $phone_number)->first();
```

use this code to for error check

```
if(empty($UserInfo)){
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors('we don't have a user with this phone number ');
            }
```

and add below code into your blade

```
@if(count($errors)>0)

    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>

            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)

                <li>{{$error}}</li>

            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

best regards

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
> var_dump($data);
```

in the view.

See what it shows up. This might help further investigate the error.

Then In accordance go ahead with

```
>  foreach($data as $moredata){ 
>      $moredata->isEmpty();  }
```

Should work.

Comment: I get an object: object(Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator)[208]

Comment: I also have just tried  {{var_dump(count($data))}} which gives a strange result. It says '3' but then jumps to '0'.